# Blueimp File Upload Multiple Widget Using Button Click Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to implement Blueimp with many form element in one page, using this [example](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page). Here is my code

```
<form class="upload-vid">
    <input type="file" name="video_survey" accept="video/mp4" class="text-left upload-text">
    <input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="pg1.v1">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="upload-btn btn btn-base btn-keep btn-tab-edit btn-base-active">
            <input type="checkbox"> Upload
        </label>
    </div>
    <br><br>
</form>

$('form.upload-vid').each(function(index, value){
    $(this).fileupload({
        url: '/user/save_video',
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            alert('asd'); //used for checking 
            var uploadBtn = $(this).find('.upload-btn');
            $('.upload-btn').off('click').on('click', function(){
                $(this).closest('form').find('.progressbar').css('width', '0%');
                data.submit();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but when i done choosing file, the add is not triggered. I am using basic plugin (minimal setup). Console not showing error or anything

**EDIT:**
Add HTML used

Comment: where is your HTML code and what does `console` shows you?

Comment: added html code, console not showing error